# Dart Language and http_server package: Exception when processing character "&"

Tags: encoding, utf-8, dart, iso-8859-1, httpserver

I'm having some trouble sending and processing some files with http_server Dart package. The method "processRequest" throws an exception when processing a body. This is the exception: *Uncaught Error: HttpException: Unhandled HTTP entity token*

I'm calling "processRequest" as follows:

```
    HttpBodyHandler.processRequest(request, defaultEncoding: Encoding.getByName("ISO-8859-1")).then((body) {
        (...)
    }, onError: _printError);
```

**This exception occurs with both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 only when the body contains the character "&". Is there any way to fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the http_server Dart package. We where trying to decode HTML entity values in the values from `multipart/form-post`. The parsing of the HTML entities was wrong and caused values with & characters in them to not work.

I have made this fix https://codereview.chromium.org/730203008, which removed the HTML entity parsing for values from `multipart/form-post`.

The browsers Chrome, Firefox and Safari might use HTML entities (in the form &#xxxxx; for form values in some cases. One case is if the attribute `accept-charset="latin1"` is set on the HTML `form` element. However in that case & characters entered in the for is not encoded, so a general decoding is not possible. The fix mentioned above removes the automatic HTML entity decoding.

Not setting `accept-charset` on the `form` element will cause UTF-8 to be used if the `Content-Type` of the HTML page hosting the form is `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Using all UTF-8 usually causes fewer problems.

Comment: sgjesse, your patch fixed the issue and now I'm being able to process a body containing the character "&". Thanks!

Comment: The bug is fixed in version 0.9.5 of the http_server package.